# parcel creates a js file, even if I'm not using js

Tags: javascript, parcel

I'm building a simple website with html and css (sass). For converting sass to css, I'm using parcel to create a bundle of the website.

The website consist of 2 files: 'index.html' and 'style.scss'. I have 2 commands in my package.json-file:

```
...
"source": "index.html"',
"scripts": {
  "start": "npx parcel",
  "build": "npx parcel build"
},
...
```

To develop my website and show the realtime changes, I'm using `npm run start`. This creates a /dist-folder with a html-file (index.html), a css-file AND a js-file. I think this js-file has to do with the HMR?

When using `npm run build`, everything works as expected.

When uploading the /dist-folder, I get an error in my console about the websocket connection. When I delete the js-file from the /dist-folder and remove the script-tag to the js-file in the index.html-file in the /dist-folder, it works!

TLDR: how can I bundle simple websites with parcel the correct way? Do I **need** a JS-file in parcel, or can I also bundle just simple html/css-websites?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your **parcel** command in package.json

Like this below:

```
...
"source": "index.html"',
"scripts": {
  "start": "parcel index.html",
  "build": "parcel build index.html --no-autoinstall"
},
...
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The index.js-file still exists and the script-tag in the index.html-file is there.